# How to seal pivoted doors?

Tags: doors, outdoor, sealing

When a pivoted door is closed, how to ensure that it is sealed around all its edges so that outdoor dust doesn't get inside, and we maximise noise isolation?

---

This:

[image]

was a pivoted door, at least at the time photo was taken.

Comment: The only suitable draft seal will be of the bristle type due to the shearing action of the door. That won't block sound well at all. This type of door just isn't designed to seal.

Comment: @isherwood - thanks.  Any idea what is it designed for?

Comment: To look interesting, I suppose.